# regex to determine if string ends with number / contain number between '//'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to evaluate bounce rate, and in order to do so i'm looping over list of url's. My problem is that i have strings like this for example:

- `www.example.com/43/test-1`
- `www.example2.com/32/test-2`

and i cant figure out a regex to test if string ends with this format:

- slash number slash string -> `/number/string`

what i manage to get so far is getting all the url's with number between slash's :

`[x["page"] for x in data if re.search(r'\d/+$', x["page"])]`

but that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\d+/[^/]+$
```

The pattern matches

- `/` - a `/`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `/` - a `/`
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/71UHFa):

```
import re
urls = ['www.example.com/43/test-1', 'www.example2.com/32/test-2']
for url in urls:
    m = re.search(r'/\d+/[^/]+$', url)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Result:

```
/43/test-1
/32/test-2
```

To only get the numbers, wrap the `\d+` with  a capturing group and access the value via `.group(1)`:

```
re.search(r'/(\d+)/[^/]+$', url)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

[One-liners](https://ideone.com/pS4CAT):

```
print([re.search(r'/\d+/[^/]+$', url).group(0) for url in urls if re.search(r'/\d+/[^/]+$', url)])
# => ['/43/test-1', '/32/test-2']
print([re.search(r'/(\d+)/[^/]+$', url).group(1) for url in urls if re.search(r'/\d+/[^/]+$', url)])
# => ['43', '32']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close and just need a slight modification:

```
re.search(r'\d/[^/]+$', x["page"])
```

This will match all URLs having a digit in the second to last path position, followed by one or more characters of any type in the final position.